# How to show a link after login on the basis of user authentication whether user has a blogging account or not

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Problem context:**

Below is my Blogger model. I am using a one-to-one relation ship with inbuilt user

```
class Blogger(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

Before logging in I get the the following Login page. ( I am using `django.contrib.auth.urls` with custom login page that extends base_generic.html.
HTML has link in the side bar About Yourself which would only show up after successful login only.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blogger-create' %}">About yourself!</a> </li>
```

When a user after sign up or login clicks on **About yourself** link then user is redirected to blogger create form where he will update his About information. User Registration creates an instance of user which would be mapped to a new instance of Blogger via **About Yourself**

**Problem**

I want to have two views `UpdateView` and `CreateView` that would ensure if a blogger instance is already mapped to user then the update view would be called. this would require conditions in the template of base_generic.html. if else conditions would use something like
`models.Blogger.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`.

The trouble is as already stated I am using inbuilt accounts\login. How to achieve this logic when a user logs in successfully then based upon the condition show the links for create and update. Logic would be something like below:

```
linked_blogger = models.Blogger.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
if linked_blogger is None:
    <li><a href="{% url 'blogger-create' %}">About yourself!</a> </li>
else:
    <li><a href="{% url 'blogger-update' blogger.id%}">About yourself!</a> </li>
```

I am not yet logged in so there is no authenticated user yet. After login once I get authenticated user I want to be able to use the if else logic.

I explored through a couple of options online but none of them appealed to me.

I am expecting to be able to send some context after redirect so that I can use that context in the page after redirection.

Comment: My first idea would be to use a CustomUserModel instead of the standard User and add the fields is_blogger (bool, if necessary) and about (TextField) directly and just use an UpdateView on the User instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, pass a context is_blogger to template from the view, then  in the templates you can hide/show the links conditionally

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):
    # this is a bare minimum filter,
    # you might have to write filter query according to your use-case
    is_blogger = Blogger.objects.filter(user=request.user).exist() 

    context = {'is_blogger': is_blogger}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

and in you html template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>

    {% if is_blogger %}
       
        <li><a href="{% url 'blogger-create' %}">About yourself!</a> </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'blogger-update' blogger.id%}">About yourself!</a> </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```